# What means of f:X → 2^Y

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an example:

X = {orange, green, purple} Y = {fruit, vegetable}

A function a: X → 2^Y are as follows:

a(orange) = {fruit}

a(green) = {fruit}

a(purple) = {vegetable}

I don't understand what is the meaning of function a: X → 2^Y? I am confused about the meaning of 2^Y. If the function is a: X → Y, I can understand, but cannot understand with 2^Y.

Reference:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.05631

Comment: It is the power set of Y (the set of all subsets of Y).  Note a(green)={fruit} rather than a(green)=fruit.

Comment: $2^Y$ is one common notation for the power set of $Y$. So, $f : X \to 2^Y$ simply means a function which takes elements of $X$, and produces subsets of $Y$. In this case, the function produces only singleton sets (which is permissible).

Comment: Thanks for replying to me. I think I lose the knowledge of the "power set". I check the wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). Now, it is clear. Thanks again.